# Как объединить два ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Делаю две выборки по модели `Picture`

```
old = Picture.where(state: 'old').order("ctr DESC").limit(20)
new = Picture.where(state: 'new').order("id DESC").limit(5)
```

Как из двух сделать один ActiveRecord::Relation? Причем порядок элеменов `old` должен остаться прежним, а `new` должны расположиться после 5ого элемента `old`.
В итоге должно получится так (o - old, + - new)

```
o o o o o + + + + + o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o
```

Немного запутанно, но очень надо )

PS Возможно ли выполнить такую задачу одним запросом вообще, вместо двух первых?

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае наверное стоит использовать UNION.
AR с ним не дружит. А arel, как выяснилось, весьма спецэфично работает для разных СУБД и не экранирует части запроса скобками (по крайней мере из коробки).

Видимо, имеет смысл сделать самому. Но если писать полностью самому то запрос будет непереносимым на другие СУБД. Можно собрать части запроса средствами AR и вручную изолировать их скобками.
Вот пример который отработал у меня на MySQL и PostgeSQL:

```
scope1 = Location.where(location_type: 'country').order(id: :desc)
scope2 = Location.where(location_type: 'city').order(label: :asc)
sql = "( #{scope1.limit(1).to_sql}) UNION ALL (#{scope2.limit(2).to_sql}) UNION ALL (#{scope1.limit(2).offset(1).to_sql})"
union = Location.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Comment: круто, тоже работает ) но результат будет массив, и соот-но не будет работать метод update_all. А он желателен )

Comment: Да, с AR промашка вышла. Но, хотя бы, всё в один запрос.

А зачем нужен `update_all`, если не секрет? Возможно это стоит реализовать как-то по-другому?

Comment: мне надо вести статистику по показам каждый картинки на главной. т.е. зашел человек, каждая картинка получает +1 к views.

Comment: Так при обновлении нам не нужен порядок.
`Picture.where(id: union.map(&:id)).update_all(<...>)`
Конечно, я согласен что мой вариант в целом не так эффективен с точки зрения использования ресурсов, но другого варианта выбрать в один запрос я не знаю.

Comment: при обновлении порядок не важен, согласен. но он важен при выводе элементов на странице

Comment: Ну так чтобы вывести на странице, у нас есть массив, полученный через `UNION` . Единственное чем он хуже для вывода - все элементы сразу загружены в память. Но при количестве записей 25 это не критично. К базе же так или иначе будет выполнено 2 запроса: 1 на выбор с `UNION` второй на апдейт.

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
old_pictures[5, 0] = new_pictures # 5-й элемент меняем на new_pictures
```

Для вашего примера:

```
old = Picture.where(state: 'old').order("ctr DESC").limit(20)
new = Picture.where(state: 'new').order("id DESC").limit(5)
old[5, 0] = new
```

После этого в `old` будет то, что вам нужно.

Comment: не понимаю, чем это может помочь?)

Comment: @АлександрИванов написал подробнее

Comment: честно, не понимаю как, но это работает. Кроме одной мелочи. Если потом сделать old.update_all(''), то изменятся все элементы, кроме тех новых, которые мы запихнули в old

Comment: @АлександрИванов вот насчет апдейта не знаю.

Comment: Этот функционал в AR пришёл Enumerable. В данном случае, его использование не есть хорошо. Сразу теряется много фишек типа ленивых запросов, обновлений, масс-апдейта и прочего.

Comment: @anoam может мне стоит удалить этот ответ, дабы не так не делали?

Answer (score 1):

```
pics = Picture.where(state: 'old').order("ctr DESC").limit(5)
pics << Picture.where(state: 'new').order("id DESC").limit(5)
pics << Picture.where(state: 'old').order("ctr DESC").limit(15).offset(5)
```

На выходе получаете ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: так не работает, когда пытаешся потом перебрать pics -  undefined method `id' for #<Picture::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb27dddb5d0>

Comment: pics.last - #<ActiveRecord::Relation

Comment: Н-да, проблема имеет место... Хороший вопрос, ищу решение.

Comment: `<<` это тоже вроде из Enumerable, со всеми вытекающими:
`users = User.where(id: 1)
users << User.where(id: 2)
users.count #=> 1
users.size #=> 2
users.to_sql #=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE \"users\".\"id\" = 1"
users.reload
users.size #=> 1`
И да, здесь наверное имеется ввиду `+` а не `<<`
`<<` - добавляет элемент в конец "как есть", т.е. у нас получается relation внутри relation'а.

Comment: Там должен был быть += Я не стал править, поскольку все равно не тот результат.